# Make Bar Chart Fill Up the Space in between Adjacent xAxis Ticks

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart as follows:-

http://jsfiddle.net/sushengloong/KQNhm/1/

I need to change it such that the bar chart appears right in between the ticks. As you can see from the above link, I tried using `pointPlacement: 'between'` but some charts are still not displayed in between the two adjacent ticks. On top of that, there are some spacing to the right of every bar chart which make the gap between the bar charts unequal.

In addition, the xAxis tick label should also appear in the middle whereby the two adjacent ticks depict the start and end of the respective month. I can't find an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the one xAxis, you cannot have "between" / "o"n option for different series. Only what you can try to do is using two xAxis.

```
xAxis:[{
    //...options
    pointPlacement: 'between'
},{
    linkedTo:0
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian but pointPlacement does not seem to be configurable for each individual axis. Instead, the API documentation states that pointPlacement is an option under plotOptions.